# Adding a Dynamic Email Backend in Django

Tags: python, django, email

I would like to let my users decide their email backend on their own. That is why I have created the email relevant keys (host, port, username...) on the users and now I try to work this (see below) backend into my Django project. Working with [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/) and the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/mail), my first attempt was to extend the default EmailBackend by my custom "UserBackend" which overrides the `__init__` function like this:

```
class UserBackend(EmailBackend):
    def __init__(self, user_id, host=None, port=None, username=None ...):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        super().init(host=user.email_host, port=user.email_port ...)
```

As this method is called (I tried to `send_mail` from the shell) it gets no `user_id`. How can I approach this differently or how would I extend my attempts to do this? I wouldn't want to rewrite Djangos mail system entirely, as it works in itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`send_email` has a parameter called `connection` ([link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail)) which seems to fit perfectly. You can get a connection by calling `get_connection` ([link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#django.core.mail.get_connection)) with the user's parameters.

```py
connection = get_connection(host=user.email_host, port=user.email_port, ...)
send_email(connection=connection, ...)
```

If you'd like to support multiple backend types, `get_connection` also supports it.

Comment: Sounds good, I will test this later. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you very much, do you know how this stands in regards to best practices?

Comment: This is simply using a public and documented part of the Django API. They may change the API in the future but I think they won't because there no reason to.

Comment: I know, I wanted to wait if there were any other answers but I guess there aren't. Thanks again @Martí